# add more route values to custom static html helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have the following problem 
I have created custom helper that returns a partial view when clicked.

[class helper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9hUO.png)
[controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66CY1.png)

the string "routevalues" only takes one string (in this case property.Part.number) and sends it to the controller.
The controller will automatically fill the string id with the value i am sending.
I want to be able to send multiple strings. 
Example: id="123", foo="bar".

```
  @Ajax.ImageActionLink("/InternalDB/img/box/" + @property.Part.part_number + ".jpg",                            
                           "popup",
                            "85px",
                            "65px",
                            "PartialViewImageRotation",                                
                             property.Part.part_number,
                                 new AjaxOptions
                                 {
                                     UpdateTargetId = "ImageRotation",
                                     InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                     HttpMethod = "GET"
                                 })


    public static IHtmlString ImageActionLink(this AjaxHelper helper, string imageUrl, string altText,string width, string height, string actionName, 
        string routeValues, AjaxOptions ajaxOptions)
    {
        var builder = new TagBuilder("img");
        builder.MergeAttribute("src", imageUrl);
        builder.MergeAttribute("alt", altText);
        builder.MergeAttribute("width", width);
        builder.MergeAttribute("height", height);
        var link = helper.ActionLink("[replaceme]", actionName+"/"+routeValues, ajaxOptions).ToHtmlString();
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(link.Replace("[replaceme]", builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing)));
    }



    public ActionResult PartialViewImageRotation(string routeValues,string id, string ImgWidthHTML5Viewer, string ImgHeightHTML5Viewer,string ImgWidthFlashPlayer,
        string ImgHeightFlashPlayer, string ImgFloatPosition ,string ImgDivWidthRotatePlayer,  string ImgDivPadding, string ImgWidthRotatePlayer, string ImgHeightRotatePlayer)
    {
        ViewBag.PartNumber = id;

        ViewBag.ImgWidthHTML5Viewer = ImgWidthHTML5Viewer;
        ViewBag.ImgHeightHTML5Viewer = ImgHeightHTML5Viewer;

        ViewBag.ImgWidthFlashPlayer = ImgWidthFlashPlayer;
        ViewBag.ImgHeightFlashPlayer = ImgHeightFlashPlayer;
        ViewBag.ImgFloatPosition = ImgFloatPosition;

        ViewBag.ImgDivWidthRotatePlayer = ImgDivWidthRotatePlayer;
        ViewBag.ImgDivPadding = ImgDivPadding;

        ViewBag.ImgWidthRotatePlayer = ImgWidthRotatePlayer;
        ViewBag.ImgHeightRotatePlayer = ImgHeightRotatePlayer;

        var firstImageRelativePath = "~/img/HTML/" + id + "/Profile.xml";
        var firstImageAbsolutePath = HttpContext.Server.MapPath(firstImageRelativePath);
        ViewBag.FirstImageCheck = System.IO.File.Exists(firstImageAbsolutePath);
        //possible problem : "\\" are doubled in the absolute path 

        var secondImageRelativePath = "~/img/SWF/" + id + "/" + id + ".swf";
        var secondImageAbsolutePath = HttpContext.Server.MapPath(secondImageRelativePath);
        ViewBag.SecondImageCheck = System.IO.File.Exists(secondImageAbsolutePath);

        return PartialView();
```

Comment: Please publish the code inside this question.

Comment: Where actually is your html-helper?

Comment: my Ajax.ImageActionLink will call the PartialViewImageRotation. The problem is that i can only fill the string id with a value. i need to fill the rest of the values as well

Comment: I have found a way to fix this. All i needed to do is to change string routeValues to object routeValues and then separete actionname from routevalues in "helper.ActionLink("[replaceme]", actionName+"/"+routeValues," and i can now send multiple values to that controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to solve this. All i needed to do is to change a few things

`public static IHtmlString ImageActionLink(this AjaxHelper helper, string imageUrl, string altText,string width, string height, string actionName, 
            object routeValues, AjaxOptions ajaxOptions)
        {
            var builder = new TagBuilder("img");
            builder.MergeAttribute("src", imageUrl);
            builder.MergeAttribute("alt", altText);
            builder.MergeAttribute("width", width);
            builder.MergeAttribute("height", height);
            var link = helper.ActionLink("[replaceme]", actionName, routeValues, ajaxOptions).ToHtmlString();
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(link.Replace("[replaceme]", builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing)));
        }`

And now I can send multiple values.